# mysql: combining columns from for tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have this 4 tables

```
table FRUIT,  ID is Primary key

|     ID    |    code |    A   |    B      | 
--------------------------------------------
|     1     |    a01  |  apple1 |  quava1  |
|     2     |    a02  |  apple2 |  quava2  |


table FLOWER, ID is Primary key

|     ID    |    code |    C   |    D      | 
--------------------------------------------
|     1     |    a01  |  Rose1 |  Plumer1  |
|     2     |    a02  |  Rose2 |  Plumer2  |


table ANIMAL, ID is Primary key

|     ID    |    code |    E        |    F      | 
--------------------------------------------
|     1     |    a01  |  butterfly1 |  cat1     |
|     2     |    a02  |  butterfly2 |  cat2     |

table DAY, code is Primary key

|    code |    G    |     
-------------------------------------
|    a01  |  Monday |  
|    a02  |  Tuesday|
```

i want to call and combined those 4 tables into like this

```
|  ID  |    A    |   B    |   C   |    D    |    E      |   F  |  G     |code  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  apple1 | quava1 | Rose1 | Plumer1 |butterfly1 | cat1 |Monday  |a01   |
|  2   |  apple2 | quava2 | Rose2 | Plumer2 |butterfly2 | cat2 |Tuesday |a02   |
```

this is the code:

```
SELECT day*, fruit*, flower*, animal* 
       FROM day 
         LEFT JOIN fruit 
              ON day.code = fruit.code 
         LEFT JOIN flower 
              ON day.code = flower.code
          LEFT JOIN flower 
              ON day.code = animal.code
          ORDER BY day.code DESC;
```

it is said that column code is ambiguous. and cannot show the table.
i need help. how can i fix this?

Comment: in your query you forget to write . between table_name and *

Comment: @gtviga Please see my answer below. Give some feedback please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this manner, using [Aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) and [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join all the tables (**including** the `animal` table which you forgot), and of course not forgetting to include the periods `.` where needed:

```
SELECT fr.ID, fr.A, fr.B, fl.C, fl.D, a.E, a.F, d.G, fr.code
FROM `day` AS d
LEFT JOIN `fruit`  AS fr  ON d.code = fr.code 
LEFT JOIN `flower` AS fl  ON d.code = fl.code
LEFT JOIN `animal` AS a   ON d.code = a.code
ORDER BY d.code ASC;
```

Comment: was this just a random drive-by downvote? any reasons to why?

Comment: Thank you CodeGodie. i've tried using Aliases, and put the dots.it works:)

Comment: @gtviga awesome. If you feel this helped please upvote my answer by clicking the up arrow on the left, and accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Thank you. Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add `.` between `column_name` and `*` like `day.*`
Try This

```
   SELECT `day`.*, fruit.*, flower.*, animal.* 
           FROM `day` 
             LEFT JOIN fruit 
                  ON `day`.code = fruit.code 
             LEFT JOIN flower 
                  ON `day`.code = flower.code
              LEFT JOIN flower 
                  ON `day`.code = animal.code
              ORDER BY `day`.code DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that you forgot a dot '.' between the table name and the *, thats becuase you are selecting id and code column from each table, you need to specify where are you selecting from when there is more then 1 options :

```
SELECT  fruit.A,fruit.B, flower.C,flower.D, animal.E,animal.F,day.G,day.code 
       FROM day 
         LEFT JOIN fruit 
              ON day.code = fruit.code 
         LEFT JOIN flower 
              ON day.code = flower.code
          LEFT JOIN animal
              ON day.code = animal.code
          ORDER BY day.code DESC;
```

Comment: why is flower in capital `FLOWER` ? does it make a difference?

Comment: I just was on another language so I pressed SHIFT :) @CodeGodie

Comment: dude, did you downvote my answer? I didnt downvote you if that was your reason